# Leaflet Map Capturing using HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, leaflet, visualforce, html2canvas

I'm trying to capture my Leaflet Map as an image using HTML2canvas, and Then append the captured image to a new Div.
The map is captured Successfully, BUT NO markers are shown on the Captured Image!!
Sometimes i got part of the icons shown on the captures map.
Here is my code:

```html
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Leaflet, 'leaflet.js')}" /> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Leaflet, 'leaflet-src.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Leaflet, 'html2canvas.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Leaflet, 'html2canvas.svg.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Leaflet, 'leaflet-image.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-image/v0.0.4/leaflet-image.js"/>


......
......

<script>
    

  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  L_PREFER_CANVAS=true;


  var snapshot = j$("[id$=snapshot]");
  var htmlMap = j$("[id$=mapDiv]");
  button=j$("[id$=snap]");
 

  //This function is called via an apex:commandButton
  function doImage(err,canvas){

    htmlMap = j$("[id$=mapDiv]");
    html2canvas(htmlMap, 
                {
      // proxy: "server.js",
      useCORS: true,
      preferCanvas: true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) 
      {

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var image=new Image();

        image.setAttribute("src",img);

        console.log(image);
        j$("[id$=snapshot]")[0].appendChild(image);
      }
    });

  }
 
  </script>
```

Here is My origional Map:
[Origional Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhGWP.png)

and This is What I got when taking a snapshot

[another snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J62PF.png)

any Ideas??

Thanks

Comment: html2canvas is good, but not perfect, I doubt it's possible to fix this with your current method. Is your original map drawn on a canvas? If so, perhaps you could bypass html2canvas completely and generate the image directly from the map (though the markers look like elements outside of the canvas, so maybe you'd need to see if there are alternative options for displaying them)

Comment: @DBS My map is generated through the controller and is Drown on a custom component. <c />
I'm not sure what do you mean by generate the image directly from the map
Thanks

Comment: @DBS BTW, I've also tried Leaflet-Print, LeafletImage, But non were helpful!